# Parentheses at the end of a C++11 lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, parentheses

I am confused with some of the examples that I have come across with C++11 lambdas. 
For eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
        cout << []()->string{return "Hello World 1!";}() << endl;

        []{cout << "Hello World 2!" << endl;}();

        string result = [](const string& str)->string {return "Hello World " + str;}("2!");
        cout << "Result: " << result << endl;

        result = [](const string& str){return "Hello World " + str;}("3!");
        cout << "Result: " << result << endl;

        string s;
        [&s](){s = "Hello World 4!";};   // does not work
        cout << s << endl; 
        [&s](){s = "Hello World 4!";}(); // works!
        cout << s << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

I am unable to figure out what the parentheses at the end are doing. Are they instantiating, as a constructor, a lambda? Given that the template for a lambda is:

```
[capture_block](parameters) mutable exception_specification -> return_type {body}
```

it baffles me that those parentheses are required for those instances to work. Can someone explain what they are why they are required?

Comment: This is a shining example on why lambdas are something that should be used sparingly. I had to read that code about 5 times over to understand the full intent.

Comment: @Richard: Sorry, no, it's not. This is the prime example of how to *misuse* them. You don't normally call it in the exact same expression that you create it in.

Comment: @PeteBecker The point of "hello world" programs is to be dense, so the reader doesn't think about the purpose behind it.

Comment: @leemes - the usual C and C++ hello world programs are nowhere near as dense as this code.

Comment: @Xeo One useful example where you define and immediately use a lambda is to assign a const variable a value which needs some complex initialization code: `const int x = []{ some init code }();` So you don't need a separate function just to make `x` const for the rest of its life. However, I can be wrong (again) :)

Comment: @leemes: I specifically said you *normally* don't call it immediately. ;) The same holds for initializing static members with a one-off function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, given that a lambda expression is basically an anonymous function, the parentheses at the end do nothing more than just call this function. So

```
result = [](const string& str){return "Hello World " + str;}("3!");
```

is just equivalent to

```
auto lambda = [](const string& str){return "Hello World " + str;};
string result = lambda("3!");
```

This holds in the same way for a lambda with no arguments, like in

```
cout << []()->string{return "Hello World 1!";}() << endl;
```

which would otherwise (if not called) try to output a lambda expression, which in itself doesn't work. By calling it it just puts out the resulting `std::string`.

Answer (score 8):

They're calling the function object!

In two phases:

```
auto l = []()->string{return "Hello World 1!";}; // make a named object
l(); // call it
```

A lambda expression evaluates to a function object. Since there's no `operator<<` overload that takes such a function object, you'd get an error if you didn't call it to produce a `std::string`.

Comment: Is this really called a function *object*? I thought one should distinguish between function objects (= objects which implement `operator()` to behave similar to a function) and ***lambda** functions*. Different concepts, different usage, similar use cases.

Comment: @leemes: Except, lambdas *are* function objects. They implement `operator()`.

Comment: Thanks to point that out! :) So they are just some syntax sugar to *define and create* function objects (derived from `std::function(...)` in one step? I just want to understand the details of *what exactly they are*.

Comment: @leemes: First, they're not derived from `std::function`, second [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/500104). The lambda expression creates an unnamed unique type and object of that type in the scope of the expression, which contains the `operator()` aswell as the captures in some way. At the point the lambda expression was written, this object is used instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. I accidentally thought they would derive from `std::function` because of some code snipped I saw where one used this to allow the storage of the lambda as a class member, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601930/c11-lambda-as-member-variable). I just wanted to know which type a lambda function is of. Now I got it I think ;)

Comment: @leemes: `std::function` (and its boost equivalent) allow *storage* of any given callable entity. A lambda-derived function object is such a callable entity, so it can be stored. :)

Comment: @leemes `std::function` is a container that stores function objects (or any callables), they don't derive from it, actually nobody should ever derive from `std::function` (at least not for simple everyday reasons).