# Using values from lambdas in C++ 11

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parentheses at the end of a C++11 lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662688/parentheses-at-the-end-of-a-c11-lambda-expression)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int j;
    [&](){j = 10;}(); // why I need the last rounded parentheses () and what is their purpose ?
    // ...
    return(0);
}
```

I get almost everything about how the lambda works, my last question is about why i need the last couple of parentheses like reported in the above code.

The blueprint for a lambda is

```
[](){}
```

Also, I'm taking an input for my lambda by reference here, I'm directly writing into `j` with this lambda, but my compiler complains about the fact that this lambda generates an unused value if i don't put the extra `()` at the end of the lambda.

So, in the end, a lambda is this

```
[](){}
```

or this

```
[](){}()
```

?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do with lambda in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *call operator* will immediately-execute the lambda.

```
int x = [] { return 5; }(); // x == 5
```

Comment: ok, now, why i need to do this ? Lambda functions are not maded to be directly used in the code ? it's not implicit the fact that i want to use lambda where i write them ?

Comment: @axis You can store a lambda function and use it whenever you like. You can even pass it to other functions.

Comment: @axis: the *point* of lambdas is exactly to define functors "on the fly".

Comment: @axis Lambdas are like functors, but not exactly the same. See this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627218/701092

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes, but i mean the assignment for later use works just like for the functors ?

Comment: @axis Yes. As the standard says: "A closure object behaves like a function object." Or technically, "The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively."

Comment: ok, perfect, now i got this, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

The `[](){}` defines a temporary lambda functor, the final `()` invokes its `operator()` (i.e. the function call operator) => you are defining a (temporary) lambda and calling it on the spot.

You may "see" it better as

```
([](){})()
 ^^^^^^ ^^ 
   ||    invokes the "function call operator"
 lambda definition
```

Answer (score 4):

A lambda function is `[](){}`. When you add the parenthesis after it, it exectutes the lambda function.

Writing `[](){}`, you simply declare the function. This gives you the ability to store it with something like `auto my_lambda = [](){}`, for a later call `my_lambda()`.

Comment: as before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110413/using-values-from-lambdas-in-c-11#comment17822360_13110419 , i don't really get this behaviour ...

Comment: so it's never implicit the fact that that lambda needs to be executed/used.